# Understanding deadlock with a simple example

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, reentrantlock

I am working on understanding deadlock basics so I came up with below code. I have two threads acquiring locks in opposite order but they're not deadlocking. When I run it I see all the printouts. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class DeadlockBasics {
  private Lock lockA = new ReentrantLock();
  private Lock lockB = new ReentrantLock();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DeadlockBasics dk = new DeadlockBasics();
    dk.execute();
  }

  private void execute() {
    new Thread(this::processThis).start();
    new Thread(this::processThat).start();
  }

  // called by thread 1
  public void processThis() {
    lockA.lock();
    // process resource A
    System.out.println("resource A -Thread1");

    lockB.lock();
    // process resource B
    System.out.println("resource B -Thread1");

    lockA.unlock();
    lockB.unlock();
  }

  // called by thread 2
  public void processThat() {
    lockB.lock();
    // process resource B
    System.out.println("resource B -Thread2");

    lockA.lock();
    // process resource A
    System.out.println("resource A -Thread2");

    lockA.unlock();
    lockB.unlock();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is no garantee which threads is start first. To get the deadlock one of the thread has to take a lock on `lockA` and then the second thread has to take a lock on `lockB` or visa versa.

```
public void processThis() {
    lockA.lock();
    // here the control should be switched to another thread
    System.out.println("resource A -Thread1");

    lockB.lock();
    ...
```

But there **may** not be enough time to switch between thread because you have just a few lines of code.. It is too fast. To emulate some long work add delay before the second lock to both methods

```
lockA.lock();
Thread.sleep(200);  // 200 milis
```

Then the second thread will be able to lock `lockB` before the first release both of them

Answer (score 1):

This could indeed result in a deadlock but not always, for example if the processThis() is completely executed and then the processThat() or vice versa there is no deadlock. You can try to add a Thread.delay(100) or a Thread.yield() to steer the threads execution towards the deadlock or even removing the unlocks to a certain deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a good example of dead lock, since ReenttrantLock is a mutual exclusion lock with same behavior as the implicit monitor lock access by using synchronized. However you don't see the deadlock because of this part:

```
private void execute() {
      new Thread(this::processThis).start();
      new Thread(this::processThat).start();
}
```

After the first thread is created and started, it will takes a while to create the second thread. It takes the JVM about 50 us or maybe even less to create a new thread, it sounds very short, but it is enough for the first thread to be finished and therefore a dead lock will not happen.

I added a `Thread.sleep();` into your code so the both threads could be executed somehow parallely.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class DeadlockBasics {
    private Lock lockA = new ReentrantLock();
    private Lock lockB = new ReentrantLock();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeadlockBasics dk = new DeadlockBasics();
        dk.execute();
    }

    private void execute() {
        new Thread(this::processThis).start();
        new Thread(this::processThat).start();
    }

    // called by thread 1
    private void processThis() {
        lockA.lock();
        // process resource A
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); //Wait for thread 2 to be executed
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread 1 will own lock a");

        lockB.lock();
        // process resource B
        System.out.println("Thread 1 will own lock b");

        lockA.unlock();
        lockB.unlock();

        // Both locks will now released from thread 1
    }

    // called by thread 2
    private void processThat() {
        lockB.lock();
        // process resource B
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread 2 will own lock b");

        lockA.lock();
        // process resource A
        System.out.println("Thread 2 will own lock a");

        lockA.unlock();
        lockB.unlock();

        // Both locks are released by thread 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

1. Release locks in the reverse order of acquiring them.  That is, `processThis` should reverse the order of removing the locks.  For your example, the order doesn't matter.  But if `processThis` attempted to acquire a new lock on A before releasing the lock on B a deadlock could again occur.  More generally, you'll find it easier to think about locks by considering their scope and by avoiding overlapping but non-enclosing scopes.
2. To better highlight the problem, I would put in call to `wait` after acquiring the first lock in each of threads, and have `execute` launch both threads *then* invoke `notify` on both threads.